# How to search for a Git commit in submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo with multiple submodules. I have a commit's hash but do not know to which submodule it belongs, how I could find it's exact submodule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git show` in all submodules, recursively; hide error messages, ignore errors; report the submodule when the hash is found (`git show` doesn't return error):

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git show -q $hash 2>/dev/null && echo $name || :'
```

See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt).

Answer (score 2):

`git submodule status` will give you a list of the currently checked out commit hash id for each submodule. You can parse that and find out the name of the submodule corresponding to the commit hash:

```
$ commit_id="14f4e19f1c"
$ git submodule status | awk -v commit_id="$commit_id" '$0 ~ commit_id {print $2}'
```

(this assumes that you are working with the latest commit hash from that submodule)